# Using NHibernate Criteria to sum across multiple properties/columns

Tags: nhibernate, criteria

Does anyone know how to express the following SQL statement using NHibernate criteria?

```
SELECT SUM(Val1 + Val2) FROM SomeTable
```

Seems simple, but AFAIK I can't seem to find a way to do this without returning an array of values, the sums of Val1 + Val2 seperately and then summing from the array, which I want to avoid.

Answer (score 7):

In comments to blog post that @Jaguar has mentioned in his answer [NHibernate and the missing OperatorProjection](http://savale.blogspot.com/2011/04/nhibernate-and-missing.html) is an alternative solution:

```
session.CreateCriteria().SetProjection(
    Projections.Property<SomeType>(val => val.Id),
    Projections.Property<SomeType>(val => val.Duration),
    Projections.SqlFunction(
        new VarArgsSQLFunction("(", "+", ")"),
        NHibernateUtil.Double,
        Projections.Property<SomeType>(val => val.Duration),
        Projections.Constant(1)
    )
).List();
```

All credit goes to [Tomek](http://savale.blogspot.com/2011/04/nhibernate-and-missing.html?showComment=1359149704745#c5901349069811347801).

This might look sth like:

```
Projections.Sum(
    Projections.SqlFunction(
        new VarArgsSQLFunction("(", "+", ")"),
        NHibernateUtil.Int32,
        Projections.Property<SomeTableType>(val => val.Val1),
        Projections.Property<SomeTableType>(val => val.Val2)
    )
)
```

Especially [`VarArgsSQLFunction`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/dialect/function/VarArgsSQLFunction.html) is useful.

Answer (score 5):

Well, after reading for the n-th time a question with this exact problem i decided to write an implementation that doesn't include writing SQL.

You can check the implementation at http://savale.blogspot.com/2011/04/nhibernate-and-missing.html with which you can write:

```
criteria.SetProjection(
                 new ArithmeticOperatorProjection("+",
                                 NHibernateUtil.Int32,
                                 Projections.Property("Prop1"), Projections.Property("Prop2")
                                                  )
                );
```

Comment: Very nice, will give it a shot!

Answer (score 1):

I guess that Val1 and Val2 are property values from your entities. It that case you can write your own custom NHibernate.Criterion.ICriterion. In your case you will just implement methods ToSqlString.

Answer (score 0):

or you can use HQL to achieve the same. it lets you operate on your .net objects and then queries the server accordingly..

you can build up your query as follows

```
var hqlQuery= string.format(" select a.prop1 + a.prop2 from ClassA as a where a.Id={0}",val);

return session.CreateQuery(hqlQuery).UniqueResult<double>();
```