# Creating NHibernate Queryover to get sum of two field product with group by

Tags: c#, nhibernate, queryover

I have two tables `Invoice` and `InvoiceLineItem`. This `InvoiceLineItem` table contains:

```
Id
InvoiceId
Quantity
UnitPrice
```

columns. I want to create NHibernate QueryOver statement to Group the invoice line items by `InvoiceId` and get the sum of the product of `UnitPrice` and `Quantity`

SQL is like this.

```sql
SELECT InvoiceId, SUM(Quantity*UnitPrice) AS Total
  FROM InvoiceLineItem
GROUP BY InvoiceId
```

I used `Projections.Sum` but I am not sure how we can multiply two columns inside that (if that is the correct way).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It doesn't look like there's a great way to do this. Building off of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24552860/497356), you could use `VarArgsSQLFunction`:

```
InvoiceLineItem lineItemAlias = null;

session.QueryOver<InvoiceLineItem>(() => lineItemAlias)
    .SelectList(list => list
        .Select(Projections.Sum(
            Projections.SqlFunction(new VarArgsSQLFunction("(", "*", ")"),
            NHibernateUtil.Double,
            Projections.Property(() => lineItemAlias.Quantity),
            Projections.Property(() => lineItemAlias.UnitPrice))))
        .SelectGroup(() => lineItemAlias.Invoice.Id)
   // TransformUsing, List<>, etc.
```

That would generate SQL that looks like this:

```sql
SELECT
    sum((this_.Quantity*this_.UnitPrice)) as y0_,
    this_.InvoiceId as y1_
FROM
    InvoiceLineItem this_
GROUP BY
    this_.InvoiceId
```